# Java/Lucene Search multiple fields for a substring

Tags: java, search, lucene

I'm Using Lucence V3.1 & Java 1.6.

I'm trying to write code (using java and lucene) that allows me to do multi-field phrase search. However, i don't want the phrase to exactly match the value in the field. What i want is to check if the phrase is actually a substring of the value in the field. I tried the following but no luck yet:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open("<lucene dir>");
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("<field-name>", "<text>"));
booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
Hits hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use quotes? Like "this is the substring". This surely works with the lucene `QueryParser`

If to be used in a `Query` use a `PhraseQuery`. See also http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html

Comment: If you mean the following: Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("<field-name>", "\"<text>\"")); then sadly it didn't work. Unless i misunderstood you.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you're suggesting i use the following:PhaseQuery query1 = new PhaseQuery(new Term("<field-name>", "<text>"));  . This is also not working! Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you make the index? (which Analyser?)

Comment: writer = new IndexWriter(new RAMDirectory(), new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_30, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30)));

Answer (score 1):

which analyzer u used while indexing??

if u used Standard Analyzer, you should not face a problem like this...

PS: always use same analyzer for both indexing and searching